# Using C++ Boost memory mapped files to create disk-back data structures

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess, memory-mapped-files

I have been looking into using Boost.Interprocess to create a disk-backed data structure. The examples on Boost Documentation (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) are all for using shared memory even though they mention that memory mapped files can also be used. I am wondering whether anyone here has used memory mapped files? Any publicly available code samples to get started (say, a memory mapped file backed map or set)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might take look at [stldb](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/stldb/) project that's being actively discussed on boost mail list. It tries to build an ACID database on top of `boost::interprocess`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Nikolai! I haven't heard of stldb (though have worked with stxxl in the past); I checked out the code and had a peripheral look it seems they do use memory mapped files to back data structures. Need to explore more before I can be definite about this.